# How to compile jsx within Sublime?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3

I'm trying to make the transition to React and I'm setting up new tools. I think I like Sublime Text 3.  I have it running now with the babel and eslint packages.  Now I'm not sure when to compile my jsx into separate js files.

I have used the babel-cli watch option, but something that automatically happens within Sublime would be ideal...not another process a developer has to manually startup.  Does the sublime-babel package somehow do this?  I didn't see any options or configurations for output directories, etc.

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/search

Answer (score -1):

You have many options.

You can run grunt, gulp, webpack to do so.

Personally I use webpack I have my scripts in package.json and run them by writhing following in console.

```
npm run webpack
npm run watch
npm run test
```

Do not use solution which is only for one IDE or Text editor and solution that are not sharable between team members.

Comment: Can you please explain your last sentence? If I'm working with IDE XYZ, why shouldn't I use an XYZ plugin to compile my code?

Comment: These IDE plugins are just calling functions and displaying results. 


Most of the transformations and loaders are javascript functions with a json setup file. 


You can set up these javascript functions and use them from terminal.
This will ensure that it will work also for your colleagues using other IDEs.

Comment: That's about as useful as answer as 'dont run eslint inside sublime, just use the command line'